# How to make a list of 12 months (loop) not starting at the first month?

Tags: excel, date, sequence, series

Given a date, ex. `05/05/2006`, I need to name 12 columns starting with the month of the date given. I realize that I need to make a list of months, I just don't know how to loop it (ie. if one of the months in the middle is December, the next one needs to be January).

The only way I know, from other programming experience, is to make the first column equal to the first month, then make nested conditional statements for the other columns

```
 IF(A1="Jan","Feb",IF(A1="Feb","Mar".......))
```

I'm sure that there's a better way to do it than brute force (plus, excel doesn't allow me to input that many nested conditionals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should do the trick:

```
=TEXT(DATE(2014,MONTH($A$1)+COLUMN()-2,1),"mmmm")
```

The starting date should be in A1 and first header in B column. If the first header is in another column, you should replace `2` in `COLUMN()-2` with the column number.

Answer (score 1):

In the first month column, use `=TEXT(A1,"MMMM")` where the date is in A1... In the subsequent columns, use `=TEXT(EDATE(DATEVALUE("1 "&B1),1),"MMMM")` to make a date from the month name, add a month and convert to text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date is in A1, and your columns are in B1 - M1:

Set B1 `= A1`.

Set C1 `= EDATE(B1, 1)`. [EDATE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/edate-function-HP010342465.aspx) adds the specified number of months to the specified date.

Copy C1 to D1 - M1.

Now you have twelve columns containing the original date and the same date on eleven successive months.

Select B1 - M1; Format Cells; under Number, select Custom; and under Type, enter `mmm`. This will format these dates to just show the abbreviated month.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A1 has the date. The following should work

```
B1= A1 (format as "mmm")
C1 =EOMONTH(B1,1) (format as "mmm")
```

Copy the above formula and format from C1 for the other columns

Comment: Lets say `A1=05/05/2006` ,`B1=May` ,`C1=#Value!`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date is in A1

```
 =TEXT(EDATE(A1,0),"MMMM")
```

The next column would be

```
 =TEXT(EDATE(A1,1),"MMMM")
```

... and so on.